# How to port this *nix-shell script to OS X?

Tags: terminal, unix

I've got a unix-shell script that's supposed to work on nix machines. This doesn't run on OS X however, due to "cp" command not defined. Changing it to "copy" didn't help.

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" | xargs -I %id% git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %id% | xargs -I % cp --parents % upd/
```

The script should make a copy of files changed in last git commit.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has more to do with the percentage sign than with cp. Because cp should be available in any case, it's such a basic command.

Comment: or "cp" on OS X doesn't know the --parents option

Comment: If you have Command Line Tools for Xcode installed you can download GNU core utilities and install the GNU version of `cp` which works with `--parents`.  I just tested it and it works nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246070/cp-parents-option-on-mac

`cp` is available on OS X, but it does not support the `--parents` option, as I guessed. Instead of using `cp --parents`, replace it with `ditto` as mentioned in the SO answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it and possibly reply with a solution.